# using svn diff command in code

Tags: c#, svn

Hi i have a problem using svn command in code behind :

```
public void SvnDiff(int rev1, int rev2)
        {
            try
            {
                var p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "svn";
                string arg = string.Format("diff -r {0}:{1} --summarize --xml > SvnDiff.xml", rev1, rev2);
                Console.WriteLine(arg);
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

When i use this command in cmd, it's working fine.
svn diff -r 2882:2888 --summarize --xml > SvnDiff.xml

but when i run my method i got this message:
svn: E020024: Error resolving case of '>'

What can i do right now to solve this ?
Thanks for any advice

Comment: Do you want to read the output directly from c# or create the SvnDiff.xml file?

Comment: I want to create SvnDiff.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `> SvnDiff.xml` part of your command line aren't arguments being passed to SVN.  They're redirecting standard output.  To do that, take a look at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx):

Since you already have RedirectStandardOutput set properly, you just need to take advantage of it.  Simply put

```
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

in front of your `p.WaitForExit();` line.

Then, just use `File.WriteAllText("SvnDiff.xml", output);`

Answer (score 1):

You can read all text and then write to the file as @Scott suggested, but it can be problematic if the output is too large.

You can instead write as the output is generated. Create a local `StreamWriter` for the file, and a method to write whenever new output data is available:

```
StreamWriter redirectStream = new StreamWriter("SvnDiff.xml")

void Redirect(object Sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  if ((e.Data != null)&&(redirectStream != null))
    redirectStream.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

and when you start the process:

```
p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(Redirect); // handler here to redirect
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.WaitForExit();

redirectStream.Flush();
redirectStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this....

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
string arg = string.Format("/K svn diff -r {0}:{1} --summarize --xml > SvnDiff.xml", rev1, rev2);
Console.WriteLine(arg);
p.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

if it works then change /K with /C

Comment: What are the `/K` and `/C` for?

Comment: @caerolus open a command prompt and type CMD /? to get help on command shell switches.

Comment: oh, didn't notice you actually executed cmd!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, I use StandardOutput and it work :)

```
var p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "svn";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("diff -r {0}:{1} --summarize --xml", rev1, rev2);
                p.Start();
                string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                p.WaitForExit();
                File.WriteAllText("SvnDiff.xml", output);
```

Thanks for all of you.